# How to make object for ajax request from knockout form?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, knockout.js

I have tried a bunch of combinations and I can't handle this.
I have a form with knockout.js binding. I need to make an object consist of values from a form and then send this object to the server by ajax() request. Iam completely lost and don't know how to continue... Please, can you help me create the object correctly?

I erased my attempts as I tried a clean workspace.

My form:

```
<form data-bind="submit: AddService">
            Name: <input data-bind="value: serviceName" /><br />
            Address: <input data-bind="value: serviceAddress" /><br />                 
            Interval:<select data-bind="options: $root.availableIntervals,value: 'selectedInterval', optionsText: 'interval'"></select><br />
            Notifications: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantNotification" /><br />
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
```

My JS:

```
<script>
function ServiceToSend(serviceName, serviceAddress, notifications, selectedInterval) {
    self.name = ko.observable(serviceName);
    self.address = ko.observable(serviceAddress);
    self.notifications = ko.observable(notifications);
    self.checkInterval = ko.observable(selectedInterval);
}      //This is the function to make object that I tried.

function ServicesViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableIntervals = [
        { interval: "1", value: 1 },
        { interval: "2", value: 2 },
        { interval: "3", value: 3 }
    ];

    serviceName = ko.observable();
    serviceAddress = ko.observable();
    wantNotification = ko.observable(false);
    selectedInterval = ko.observable();

    self.AddService = function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:55972/api/services/add/",
            data: {
                //I Need object here consist of form elements.
            },
        }).done(function (msg) {
        });
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ServicesViewModel());
```

I don't know where and how to call new SendServiceToSend(). Every time I tried to call it, I got undefined or some weird *string of characters after displaying it by console.log().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout passes the formElement for you on the [submit binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html). So you just need to add the parameter to the `AddService()` function to start using it. Then you can use jQuerys [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to convert the form element to a url encoded string that the ajax request can use.

> KO passes the form element as a parameter to your submit handler function. You can ignore that parameter if you want, or there are various ways you might want to use it, for example:

So for example, you don't need `ServiceToSend()` and you can instead do the following:

```
self.AddService = function (formElement) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:55972/api/services/add/",
        data: $( formElement ).serialize(),
    }).done(function (msg) {
    });
};
```

A small semi-related note: Knockout by default does not submit the form so you don't have to worry about preventing the default action of a HTML form, which is to actually submit to the server.

> When you use the submit binding on a form, Knockout will prevent the browser’s default submit action for that form.

Comment: I tried it as you said, I hope this is as parameter right: (serviceName, serviceAddress, wantNotification, selectedInterval) but it still add services with null values: {"serviceId":4171,"name":null,"address":null,"notifications":false,"checkInterval":0,"checks":null,"lastCheck":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}]

Comment: what do you mean "I hope this is as parameter right:" ? did you try it exactly as I have in the answer?

Comment: Yea, I reliazed it few seconds after adding comment.. :D I tried it exactly as you wrote and still with null values. :( Also I tried to display what is the going on here by: serviceName = $(formElement).serialize();
            console.log(serviceName); 
And it display nothing.

Comment: I would double check how you create your form.

Comment: Double check ? Like just watch the code and try find where I did misstake or it's some function ? :D Iam beginner so sorry for my rudeness. :| I got an idea to use click-binding insted submit but I don't know if it would give me values of inputs..

Comment: One thing I would try is to get rid of the `data-bind="value: serviceName"` on your form elements and try that. I would keep the form as a `submit` bind too. Also make sure you enter something the inputs

Comment: Ok I used <input type="text" name="name" /> and it displays me the value! :) Thanks!!!! :)

Comment: great! feel free to accept the answer if its solved.

Comment: For sure I did! :)

Comment: I have last issue. {"serviceId":4192,"name":"Service2","address":"192.0.0.1","notifications":false,"checkInterval":3,"checks":null,"lastCheck":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},
notification is still false even if I select it. :/

Comment: did you remove the data bind from the input element too?

Comment: If using this approach why not replace knockout with jquery.  Here is how you convert a view model to json.  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Answer (score 0):

serviceName is NOT part of your ServicesViewModel(), try:

```
self.serviceName = ko.observable();
self.serviceAddress = ko.observable();
self.wantNotification = ko.observable(false);
self.selectedInterval = ko.observable();
```

call ko.toJSON inside AddService

```
self.AddService = function () {
    var dataToSend = ko.toJson(self)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:55972/api/services/add/",
        data: dataToSend,
    }).done(function (msg) {
    });
};
```

Note: dataToSend will contain all the data in your view model.  This is likely NOT what you want.  To send only form data, create a new object with only form data.  Use the ['with'](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) data binding on the form.  Call ko.toJSON with that object.  Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afrievalt/uewpyfms/1/)

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't add service with values. :( It work well, but it looks like I don't need a json to send. This is the format from Andrew's solution and it adding without problem: name=dad&address=dada&checkInterval=1&notifications=true
Is there some way to make this format with ko? I would like to use knockout form, so it would be great if it's possible.

Comment: You CAN use knockout.  If you don't want JSON like your question states, maybe re-ask the question.  You can also transform your data.  "name=" + data.name + "&address=" + data.address